# Slow results posting - nothing else wrong, what's the problem?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I use PHP and MySQL to manage the content on my server/site (I have a video site).
Lately, the results of any page started coming really slow, not like any other site.
The CPU and Memory of the server are at 0-5% so overhead is not a problem.
What I do is query a database for entries and then show them, along with their thumbanil/score and other info.
What happens is when I open a results page, it does not get all the results at once, they add up one by one.
Is that normal?! of course not...to understand better: what happens is that the header loads, and then the content (many thumbnails linking to other pages) starts loading, but like this: the first 3 thumbs appear, then the next 4, then the next 2, then 4,then... until the end, when finally the bottom of my page loads, meaning the contact link and ToS.

Is there any idea crossing your mind?

I mention that my server has good hardware condition, strong CPU and lots of RAM which are all at a minimum of used % and also mention that the ping to my server is around 40ms (I live in central Europe, the server is in Chicago)

My database contains around 10,000 entries, each page shows 24 entries which are being processed each by this php script:

```
while($arr=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
<div class="thumb" align="center">
<?php
    echo "<a href='videos/".$arr['title'].".php'>";
    ?>
<img src="thumbs/<?php  
$title=basename($arr['address']);
$title=substr($title,0,strlen($title)-4); 
echo $title;
?>_5.jpg" onMouseOver="startThumbSlide('<?php echo $title; ?>', '5', 'thumbs/<?php echo $title.'_'; ?>')" onMouseOut='stopThumbSlide();' id='pic_<?php echo $title; ?>'  width="200px" height="150px"/>
<br />
<div align="left">
<?php
rating_form($arr['address']);
echo '</div>';
echo "</a>";
echo "<a href='videos/".$arr['title'].".php' class=\"thumba\"     onMouseOver=\"startThumbSlide('".$title."', '5', 'thumbs/".$title.'_'."')\" onMouseOut='stopThumbSlide();'>".$arr['title']."</a><br>
<span style=\"font: normal 10px verdana; color:#999;\">Viewed: ".$arr['views']." times</span>".'
<span style="float:right; font: normal 10px verdana; color:#999;">'.$arr['lenght'].'</span>    </center>'."
</div>";}
```

Thanks a million times in advance to any advise you might give me!
Cheers!

PS: I have to add that the traffic has not changed, actually the site worked better 2 weeks ago when I had double the traffic I have now, and no settings were changed on my server, just slight scripting changes, but I can't remember exactly what I changed when this started happening...

Edit: Here is the MySQL query I use to get my data from the database, including search string manipulation, the search string variable is $s, this code comes after I have stripped tags and trimmed it.
Here is the code:

```
$pattern='/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/';
$s=preg_replace($pattern,' ',$s);
$query="SELECT
    *, 
    CASE when title like '%".$s."%' then 1 else 0 END as titlematch, 
    CASE when tags like '%".$s."%' then 1 else 0 END as tagsmatch,
    MATCH (title, tags) AGAINST ('*".$s."*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
FROM videos
WHERE
    (title like '%".$s."%' OR
    tags like '%".$s."%' OR
    MATCH (title, tags) AGAINST ('*".$s."*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
AND page=1
ORDER by
    titlematch desc, tagsmatch desc, relevance desc
";

$all = mysql_query($query);

$total = mysql_num_rows($all);
if($total>0){
$n1=$start-1;

$result = mysql_query($query. " LIMIT $n1,$max");

while($arr=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
[...This part is already posted...]
```

Also, I would like to add that I currently have 2 indexes, one for the index field and one fulltext, for the title and tags fields.

Comment: I doubt this portion of your script has anything to do with it nor your database query. How are the thumbnails created? Are they cached?

Comment: Thumbnails are created using ffmpeg, stored in the thumbs folder. This is done only once, when the video is uploaded.I suspect this piece of code because this takes care of displaying each item and the problem at my script is that at the item displaying, it prints results much slower than it should... Do you have any ideas about it? Thanks for your reply,btw.

Comment: and please tell me, what do you mean by cache? cached by the internet user's computer? Could you provide me a short explanation? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, it can be very difficult to diagnose problems like these. But there are some tools that might shed some light on the problem, and lead you to a more specific area to focus on.

First, I'd start with a basic internet speed test, like: http://www.speedtest.net/ Verify that everyone else's pages are in fact loading quickly.

Then, just for kicks, get someone outside your country to try to load your site, and see if it's slow for them too. You might be able to try this yourself by loading your site through a foreign proxy. I suggest all this because those who control the pipes are known to throttle things that are using a lot of bandwidth, like videos sites, for example.

While it sounds like it's the HTML that is loading slowly, and not necessarily server processing speed, it couldn't hurt to check your database speed. I'd use a tool like phpMyAdmin, and run your SQL query and just see if the results return quickly. If they're slow, it could be an inefficiently written SQL query, or some database settings that need to be tweaked. Just doing a Google search for "mySQL suddenly very slow" brings up many posts that are resolved simply by updating to the latest version of mySQL.

Those are all the ideas I have for now. Let me know if you discover anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try to test it and see what happens... maybe get a differential diagnosis... yeah... So thanks again, and for the MySQL, I am editing my question to include my query. Cheers!

Comment: And if you answer, I am fairly new to this site, do you know why do I have a -2 reputation on this question? 2 persons voted me down? why?...

Comment: Also, wouldn't speedtest actually tell me my home internet connection download speed?, is there anything to tell me about some else's connection speed to my website? Because my connection speed is good, and the content that is loading slowly is not made of images(which are optimized, all the thumbs are small), but of actual data, like html code that is supposed to be generated by php.

Comment: I'm new myself... But some people get cranky if they think a question is too vague, or has too many open-ended potential answers. I'm not bothered by it personally

Comment: Hmm, the speed test probably doesn't help much then. New idea: get the "FireBug" toolbar for FireFox and run what I think is the "net" tab profiler. Then load your page and watch the millisecond loading speeds for all of the items, like your thumbs, for trouble. While you're installing FF plugins, maybe try the "YSlow" one as well and see if it yeilds any clues.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I use FF as my browser of choice and I do have FireBug installed as I use the "Inspect this element" right-click option often, but now I realize I never had the curiosity to check the net tab... :|...I always thought it had to do with .Net so I just never clicked it (duh...)... thanks a lot, anyway, I shall keep you posted of any changes that may occur! The internet is a better place just because of your thoughtful answers to my question! :D Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, I have used phpMyAdmin to query the database for the exact same thing as my query does and the results come amazingly fast! So MySQL is ok, updated and all, just as I thought it would be (I have spent around 3 days optimizing my database for speed result return)... So this failed... I'll get to another idea... maybe speed test for my server or something... and maybe thumbnail checking?... :-/

Comment: I have used the net tab of firebug and now i'm even more confused... I load 24 pics in total, all of which are in a folder. when asking for a pic, the waiting time is over 100ms at each! wtf?!... What could be happening?! the pics are 200x150 each and 20KB each... what could be wrong?!... thanks in advance for a reply...

Comment: @JohnDavidParsons let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1301/discussion-between-andrei-chirtes-and-john-david-parsons)